# UIView Animation - strange behaviour (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiview

I have a UIImageView that contains an animated picture (sequence of pictures) i'm trying to move the UIImageView from its current position to the right of the screen (from middle to right of the screen) to create a running effect of the character

when i press the button that i want to trigger the animation the image suddenly disappear then get animated from the left side off the screen to the middle. I have no idea why the UIImageView is being moved off the screen (left side)

this is my code

```
@IBAction func correctButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
        if isTrue {
            winAudio.play()
            playRunAnimation()
            UIView.animateWithDuration(3, animations: { () -> Void in
                var frame = self.animatedImage.frame
                frame.origin.x += (self.animatedImage.superview?.frame.width)!
                self.animatedImage.frame = frame
            })
        }
    }
```

EDIT :

this is how i animate my UIImageView

```
func playIdelAnimation() {
        self.image = UIImage(named: "Idel1.png")
        var imageArray = [UIImage]()
        for i in 1...10 {
            let str = "Idle\(i).png"
            let imageName = UIImage(named: str)!
            imageArray.append(imageName)
        }
        self.animationImages = imageArray
        self.animationDuration = 0.5
        self.startAnimating()
    }
```

self.image = UIImage(named: "Idel1.png")
is to set a default picture for the UIImageView
then im creating an array of UIImage to animate it in the UIImageView

using (self) because i have a custom class for the UIImageView

Comment: Do you use some constraints on the animatedImage ?

Comment: yes i did use some constraints

Comment: They could cause the problem because if you change the origin of the image the constraints are still there and want to keep the image at its position.

Comment: ok thanks i will try to remove them and place the UIImageView programmatically

Comment: no i don't think thats the best solution. Just change the constraints in your animation too.

Comment: i actually don't know how to do that.

Comment: i'll post a answer in a sec.

Answer (score 0):

First you need a reference to the constraints of the imageview from your interfacebuilder (*Don't forget to connect the outlet in the interfacebuilder with the constraints*):

```
 @IBOutlet weak var leftConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
 @IBOutlet weak var rightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

I assume your image has a *leftConstraint.constant = 0* and *rightConstraint.constant = self.view.frame.width*

Then you animate with:

```
self.leftConstraint.constant = self.view.frame.width
self.rightConstraint.constant = self.view.frame.width + self.animatedImage.frame.width

UIView.animateWithDuration(3.0) {
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

I hope this helps. Good luck.

Comment: Did you connect the constraints with the interfacebuilder? What happens to you image with this code?

Comment: The same thing. the UIImageView disappear then get animated from off the screen to the origin position of the UIImageView

Comment: Can you provide an example application. Just the Image and your bug?

Comment: At the current time i cant. I have noticed that everything works fine if it was just a single image, but when i create an animated image (sequence of picture) the bug rise

Comment: Please post some code on how you create you image or how you animate it.

Comment: Now please show me how you add the view image to your screen

Comment: i added the UIImageView from the storyboard.

Comment: But self.image = UIImage(named: "Idel1.png") is a image and no uiimageview

Comment: Sorry i think there is something wrong in your implementation but without the code its just guessing.